# Apply A regression monthly - Using always last 52-weekly prices - Problems with 2 frequencies

Tags: r, regression, frequency, rolling-computation

I am currently trying to implement the following model:

[image]

I want to regress every month - stock prices of the last 52-weeks on ordinal variables which basically count the number of weeks ago a specific price was observed. For instance - Yesterdays price will get regressed on 1, the price 2 days ago on 2 and so on...

The main problem I have is to follow this approach on a monthly basis - using data of the last 52- weeks. Is there a way to include 2 frequencies in some of the apply functions?

I just need to find a way how the apply functions like apply.monthly() is using always the last 52- data points from my weekly share prices.

I would be happy if somebody would have an idea on that!

```
t<- seq(from=52,to=1,by=-1)
t2<- t**2
seq.regression<- function(x,y=t,z=t2){
                 modell<- lm(x ~ t+t2)
                 out<- modell$coefficients[3]
                 return(out)
                  }
seq.regression(DATA)
```

Comment: Have you try with the zoo package, there is a rolling function to apply a function in a certain window and then move the window further. Hear is the documentation:
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/zoo/versions/1.8-1/topics/rollapply

Comment: Indeed, I tried rollapply in the meanwhile - I have the problem that the number of weeks per month is varying from 4 to 5 so that I cant use a fixed value for the "by" argument.

Comment: Can't you use the rollapply by month, and work the date problems with month() function of lubridate package ?